# receive byte[] from asp.net website with webrequest

Tags: c#, asp.net, webrequest

I need to get some information from a website. that website is not meant to be accessed from a browser.  so let's say that the website contains a byte array:  I want to get that byte array from a console application.

```
// c# code for asp website
protected byte[] data;
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    data = new byte[] { 1, 100, 200, 255 };  // the byte array that I want to send
}

// the asp content
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
       <div>
          <%=data%>
       </div>
   </form>
</body>
```

if 'data' would have been a string I would be able to retrieve that by parsing the responseFromServer variable defined in the following code.

```
        // Create a request using a URL that can receive a post. 
        WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("http://localhost:4444/WebSite2/HelloFromC.aspx");
        // Set the Method property of the request to POST.
        request.Method = "POST";
        // Create POST data and convert it to a byte array.
        string postData = "This is a test that posts this string to a Web server.";
        byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);
        // Set the ContentType property of the WebRequest.
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        // Set the ContentLength property of the WebRequest.
        request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
        // Get the request stream.
        Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();
        // Write the data to the request stream.
        dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
        // Close the Stream object.
        dataStream.Close();
        // Get the response.
        WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
        // Display the status.
        Console.WriteLine(((HttpWebResponse)response).StatusDescription);
        // Get the stream containing content returned by the server.
        dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
        // Open the stream using a StreamReader for easy access.
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
        // Read the content.
        string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
        // Display the content.
        Console.WriteLine(responseFromServer);
        // Clean up the streams.
        reader.Close();
        dataStream.Close();
        response.Close();
```

Things that I have tried:

I have tried converting the byte array { 1, 100, 200, 255 } to ASCII. then with the encoding class converting it back to a byte array. the problem with ASCII is that it does not hold 256 characters. Maybe I should use a different type of encoding. But I have to make sure that whatever class of encoding I use is supported by my website...

Comment: Have you looked at doing this with a web service?

Comment: It's not clear whether your problem is sending the post data, or receiving the response data. Have you looked into WebClient by the way? It's a lot simpler for things like this...

Comment: Don't use a regular aspx page for your website.  Use an ashx file (generic handler).  You have complete control over the markup emitted.

Comment: I have not looked into that. How can I get started with that?

Comment: thanks a lot. I obviously should be using a different technique. the reason why I decided to use a website was because there are a lot of companies that can host a website for really cheap. If I created a console application where it waits for tcpconnections with the TcpListener class then that will be easier. But to host that kind of service will be more expensive plus harder to find. that's why I am trying to implement this with a website...

Comment: Create a web service.  Most hosting providers support them, as they are part of asp.net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following on from the comments above you might like to look at this tutorial on handlers (as chris lively suggested) http://www.dotnetperls.com/ashx

It might also help to give a few more details of the end goal. Are you always trying to push out a byte array? If so perhaps a web service might help. [A web service tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/webservices/myservice.aspx)

How will you consume this data? In a different webpage or a windows application?

Answer (score 2):

use something similar to

```
byte[] myBinaryResponse = new byte[response.ContentLength];
response.GetResponseStream().Read (myBinaryResponse, 0, myBinaryResponse.Length);
```

Comment: how could I then get rid of the header information that comes from the website and just keep the byte array. If I use that technique then the header information will be a byte array as well. Maybe the header information is always the same length and I can trim `myBinaryResponse` ....

Comment: According to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebresponse.getresponsestream.aspx the above should already be without the http header... or do you mean any HTML code from the `.aspx` ?

Comment: Yeah but when I place the byte array in <%=data%> the website does not send the data byte array unless it is converted to a string. In other words when I open that site with a browser it displays System.Byte[]...

Comment: I am confused - your question was how to receive the data as byte[], the above code does exactly that... now your question is how to send it ? please clarify.

Comment: I want to send the byte {1,100,200,255} array to a client from a website. the client is using a console application. when he connects to that website using a web request I want the website to send that byte array. the byte array get's created dynamically...